# Android Studio best practices on app modules

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I'm trying to understand the concept of modules on Android. I've read [this article on the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html), but I'm a bit confused. Here is stated:

> An Android Application Module is the container for your application's source code, resource files, and application level settings, such as the module-level build file, resource files, and Android Manifest file. The application module contents are eventually built into the .apk file that gets installed on a device.

and that's pretty much all the documentation I've found on this. I still don't understand in which cases would make sense to create different modules. I know that it may be vary from case to case, but ideally what would be the minimum logical size of a module?

**A practical example**

I'm building an app with a drawer view. Each button of the drawer will open a fragment which will have some logic to it. Would it make sense to make a module that contains only a fragment and a few java classes with no activities in it?

I'd really like to know which are the best practices on this.

Thank you.

Comment: It only makes sense to separate, if it is something really far away. As a general rule I only start a separate module if I plan to later on release that module as an open source library. This level of separation you suggest makes sense IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Can you elaborate what do you exactly mean by "far away"?

Comment: I'll give you a real example. I work in a very big app with LOADS of RecyclerView. We need a lot of functionality for those (scrolling Loaders, headers n footers, etc) that could eventually be used by any other project I work at. I developed those tools in a different module and when it was all working and good I moved it to a separate project and released in Github (https://github.com/eyeem/RecyclerViewTools).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the best argument for breaking code and resources into modules is reusability. If not for multiple dependents of such a module, why would you need to separate this code out into a module at all? If you only ever have one application, there's not much need to have this code broken out into a module.

As soon as you have multiple applications sharing the same code, then I think a module is justified.  A module could be many things. It could be a base application that contains the bulk of the code. It could contain the "Model" aspect of your application, or maybe an API or networking layer. It could be a container for proprietary algorithms. It could be some generalized code that you're planning to open-source. Who knows?

Consider it from the opposite angle. What's the risk of doing this now if you don't really need to? Maybe mental overhead? Having to think about and maintain this module may be more trouble than its worth if you don't have a good reason to do it in the first place.

What is the cost of deferring this decision?  Is there any compelling reason why this code couldn't be refactored out of the main application into a module at some later point?

Something as small as a single Fragment for a single UI component sounds like something that doesn't need to be in its own module.