# How to decide whether to create or not to create module in multi module gradle/maven project?

Tags: spring, maven, gradle, spring-rest

I was going through `Netflix` repo on `GitHub`, their every project is a multi-module project. I have started learning and implementing it. I did create two `spring-rest` modules in a project. I end up getting `address already in use exception` which is very obvious because port 8080 is consumed by one of the service.

I have few question regarding the multi-module project:

- When to create sub-module and when to create a separate project? any hard and fast rule to create a module?
- Best practices to be followed in multi-module projects?
- How to handle the port? manually assigning the port is error-prone

Comment: I'd split this out into several questions. As it stands this one is a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: I don't have enough content to post, SO will accept the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question is a poor fit for SO. We have three semi-related questions, only some of which will get a proper answer. Not to mention the answers will be highly subjective. There just is no hard-and-fast rule for your first question, for example. It really depends, and a discussion of these dependencies would not fit well with a Q & A site like this.

Comment: Anyway, we can probably direct all interest from here to what is essentially a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37230497/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio best practices on app modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230497/android-studio-best-practices-on-app-modules)

Comment: I feel very sad. the whole purpose of SO was to help each other, Now people here drag each other in a mud. That too for what? Some points :(

Comment: No one is dragging anyone in the mud, so relax. The purpose of SO is clearly stated in the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour as well as the Meta conversation captured here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292176/1531971